# Xpath - Get parent class by matching two child nodes

Tags: xpath

I'd like to use xpath to select a link whose `class="watchListItem"`, `span="icon icon_checked"`, and `h3="a test"`. I can use xpath to get either matching link and span, or link and h3, but not link, span, and h3.

Here's what I've tried:

```
//*[@class = 'watchListItem']/span[@class = 'icon icon_checked']

//*[@class= 'watchListItem']/h3[text()='AA']
```

I'm looking for something like this:

`//*[@class = 'watchListItem']//*[span[@class = 'icon icon_checked'] and h3[text()='AA']]`

```
<li>
<a class="watchListItem" data-id="thisid1" href="javascript:void(0);">
<span class="icon icon_checked"/>
<h3 class="itemList_heading">a test</h3>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a class="watchListItem" data-id="thisid2" href="javascript:void(0);">
<span class="icon icon_unchecked"/>
<h3 class="itemList_heading">another test</h3>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a class="watchListItem" data-id="thisid3" href="javascript:void(0);">
<span class="icon icon_checked"/>
<h3 class="itemList_heading">yet another test</h3>
</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `child::` location paths like so:

```
//a[@class="watchListItem"
    and child::span[@class="icon icon_checked"]
    and child::h3[text()="another test"]]
```

This would select the anchor with `data-id="thisid3"`.

Comment: I came up with a similar answer but I used `.//span` instead of `child::span`. Do you know what the difference is if any? Will `::child` only select direct children or will it select any descendant? Not that it matters in the case. Just curious.

Comment: @Ben though .// would select descendants, not only children.